# How to do forward analysis in Fritz

Tags: analysis, fritz

In Arena chess, there is an option to do analysis in direction, 'forward or backward'. Check the picture.

[image]

I think by default, Fritz does backward analysis. Is there a way to change it into forward analysis.

Comment: What's the difference between each type of analysis?

Comment: @David I'm assuming it analyzes every position of the game in either backward or forward direction. I would say backward makes more sense since then the engine already "knows" how the game ended. It doesn't make much of a difference either way. Question to the OP: why exactly do you want forward analysis?

Comment: I don't know the difference between the two of them. I just wanna know if this feature is available in Fritz. Do you know the difference between them? @koedem

Comment: I mean, I just described it. It determines in what order the moves are looked at. So if your game is 1.e4 e5 2.Bc4 Bc5 3.Qh5 Nf6 4.Qxf7#, then a forward analysis will first look at the starting position, then the position after 1.e4 and so on. A backward analysis will first look at the final position, then the position before 4.Qxf7# and so on. The result of those two analyses will be very similar but backward sometimes makes a bit more sense to as mentioned tell the engine how some move turned out (roughly speaking).

Comment: @JanetMThomas Why care about a feature you don't even understand what it's doing? With the information you give in the question, it coudl just as well be that Fritz can do it under a completely different name and nobody would find out

Comment: @David This doesn't answer the original poster's question. Instead, you are asking questions. If you have a question, feel free to make a new one on this very website.

Comment: @user904963 If I knew how to answer the question, I'd write an answer, not a comment. Comments are for clarification and discussion of the matter being addressed.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such feature in Fritz. It will run the game analysis backwards. However you can fine-tune game analysis almost anyway you want:

- analysis depth in terms of plies (half-moves)
- option for including/excluding non-main lines
- centipawn loss threshold
- analysis for one side only (or for both)
- analysis time per game and per move
- the amount of commentary (just turn off Fritz commentary if it annoys you)
- etc. (hash table size, number of CPU cores used, engines, almost everything is customizable)

If you want to analyze only up to a certain move, it's also possible: just indicate up to which move the analysis goes. The analysis will still go in the reverse direction starting from the move you indicated. There's also a quick blunder check analysis.

Note. *Fritz sometimes comes bundled with ChessBase (database) that contains millions of games and you can run Fritz analysis of any game in it from 1560 to the present time. Although Fritz includes lots of beginner features, it primarily targets professionals. Nowadays there are many free programs available that beginners and even amateurs might prefer who don't need the ChessBase program with its extensive search options.*